# Correlation between $u$ and $\partial_\nu u$ on $\partial \Omega$ for a give PDE

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Given a bounded area $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ which is at least of class $C^3$. If now there is a function $u$ satisfying the PDE

\begin{align*}
\Delta u &= f~~~\text{in }\Omega \\
u &= 0 ~~~\text{in } \partial\Omega,
\end{align*}
for some smooth function $f$. Is it then possible to show that $$\partial_\nu u \overset{?}{=} 0$$
on $\partial \Omega$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to show that result because it is in general not true. Think for instance in the PDE
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
-\Delta u = 4,& \textrm{in } \Omega \\
u = 0,& \textrm{on } \partial \Omega
\end{array}\right.
$$

where $\Omega=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2 < 1\}$.

The exact solution is $u=1-x^2-y^2$, which does not have zero normal derivative on $\partial \Omega$.

Comment: I guess you are missing "$<$" inside the definition of $\Omega$.

Comment: Thanks, I'll correct it.